# How to handle failed jobs on queueable notifications

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-notification

When using queueable notifications:

```
class MyNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{

    use Queueable;
}
```

How do I handle failed jobs? If I'd have dispatched the email/notification via a job class I could use the failed method:

```
public function failed(Exception $exception) {

  Log::debug('MyNotification failed');

}
```

However the failed method in a notification doesn't work

Comment: The failed method works in notifications...

Comment: So the failed() method above placed in the MyNotification class should work? Its not logging the error for me. Is there some other class I need to import to fire the failed() method.

Answer (score 1):

You should check Laravel documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#failed-job-events).

For example, in your AppServiceProvider you can add:

```
public function boot()
{
    Queue::failing(function (JobFailed $event) {
        // $event->connectionName
        // $event->job
        // $event->exception
    });
}
```

Handling of the failed job is not responsibility of the notifications but of the queues.

Comment: Simply dropping a link is not an answer, propose a solution to the OP on SO, and even when linking to docs, copy-paste the part where OP would find a solution in case the website goes down

Comment: @CaddyDZ thanks for the comment, I will edit my  answer to explain more

Comment: Isn't that going to handle all failed jobs though? I know I could filter but I'm wondering if there is a way to handle failed jobs on the notification class.

Answer (score 1):

Caddy DZ is correct there is a handle() method for notifications:
https://github.com/illuminate/notifications/blob/master/SendQueuedNotifications.php#L92

My issue was not importing the Exception class, code should be:

```
public function failed(\Exception $exception) {

  Log::debug('MyNotification failed');

}
```